# Finding the nth term in a Fibonacci sequence using for loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I need to specifically use for loops to find the nth term in a Fibonacci sequence. I tried to make it so that the main method tells method generateFibonnaci the nth term it needs to find and assign n as the limit of the second for loop, which will find the nth term recursively up until the limiting number n. For example, when input is 2, the plan is for the Fibonacci formula to run twice and return 1, but it's returning 5 in this case. I suspect that the problem lies within the parameters for the for loop, but I'm not completely sure.

```
class Fibonnaci
{
    public static int generateFibonacci(int input)
    {
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 1;
        int fibonacci = 0;
        int n = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < input; i++)
        {
            n = input;

            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                fibonacci = num1 + num2;
                num1 = num2;
                num2 = fibonacci;
            }
        }

        return fibonacci;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int [] inputs = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 16, 21, 31, 41, 46, 1, 1, 2, 11};

        for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(generateFibonacci(inputs[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < input; i++){ n = input;` you don't need this outer loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the `for` loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < input - 1; i++) {
    fibonacci = num1 + num2;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = fibonacci;
}
```

This should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

This should be the answer to your Question.

```
for (int j = 1; j <= input; j++) {
        if (j == 1) {
            fibonacci = num1;
            continue;
        }
        if (j == 2) {
            fibonacci = num2;
            continue;
        }
        fibonacci = num1 + num2;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = fibonacci;
    }
```

don't use outer for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just instead of

```
n = input;

use this:

n = i;
```

And the reason that negative values are printed in the output is that
int cannot store that large number in it.Because of the size of the int.
And the Fibonacci sequence that we are working on it is start with 0.

Comment: You can also use recursive algorithm.